# python, Django added new celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

i'm new to python celery, and thus my question, i added recently 3 new tasks that looks like this :

```
@shared_task(name="3rd-task",acks_late=True, autoretry_for=(Exception,), retry_backoff=True)
```

when i run it from console, everything is fin, but when i try to run via periodic_task in Django i get this error

```
AttributeError at /admin/django_celery_beat/periodictask/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delay'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhostadmin/django_celery_beat/periodictask/
Django Version:     2.0.4
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delay'

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_celery_beat/admin.py in <listcomp>, line 184
```

i think, problem is that i didn't register it somewhere

```
[EDIT]

def run_tasks(self, request, queryset):
        self.celery_app.loader.import_default_modules()
        print("asdasd")
        tasks = [(self.celery_app.tasks.get(task.task),
                loads(task.args),
                loads(task.kwargs))
                for task in queryset]
        task_ids = [task.delay(*args, **kwargs) <-- here is error
                    for task, args, kwargs in tasks]
        tasks_run = len(task_ids)
        self.message_user(
            request,
            _('{0} task{1} {2} successfully run').format(
                tasks_run,
                pluralize(tasks_run),
                pluralize(tasks_run, _('was,were')),
            ),
        )
```

Comment: can you add the code where you call this function

Comment: and also the task code

Comment: problem is in this line self.celery_app.tasks.get(task.task)

Comment: @nishant this worked so far, what should i change ?